# Converting an Access Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this query to a SQL Server view

```
SELECT 
    IIF([tblStockMovementsDate] ! [LocationType] = 3, [tblShops] ! [Type], [tblLocationType] ! [LocationTypeDesc]) AS [LocationTypeDesc],
    tblStockMovementsDate.[Location],
    qryAllLocations.[WarehouseName],
    SUM (([tblStockMovementsdate] ! [MovementQtyHangers] + ([tblStockMovementsdate] ! [MovementQtyBoxes] * Iif(Isnull([qryGarmentsPerBox] ! [GarmentsPerBox]), 1, [qryGarmentsPerBox] ! [GarmentsPerBox]))) * [qryUnitPrice] ! [UnitPrice]) AS [TotalValue],
    IIF ([tblShops] ! [Type] = 'Concession', 4, [tblStockMovementsDate] ! [LocationType]) AS [LocationType]
FROM   
    (((((tblStockMovementsDate
INNER JOIN 
    tblLocationType ON tblStockMovementsDate.[LocationType] = tblLocationType.[LocationType])
INNER JOIN 
    qryAllLocations ON tblStockMovementsDate.[Location] = qryAllLocations.[WarehouseRef])
LEFT JOIN 
    qryGarmentsPerBox ON (tblStockMovementsDate.[Location] = qryGarmentsPerBox.[WarehouseRef])
                      AND (tblStockMovementsDate.[StockCode] = qryGarmentsPerBox.[StockCode]))
LEFT JOIN 
    qryUnitPrice ON tblStockMovementsDate.[StockCode] = qryUnitPrice.[StockCode])
LEFT JOIN 
    tblShops ON tblStockMovementsDate.[Location] = tblShops.[ShopRef])
INNER JOIN 
    tblStock ON tblStockMovementsDate.[StockCode] = tblStock.[StockCode]
WHERE  
    ((IIF ([tblShops].[Clearance] = 0, [tblStock].[DeadCode] = 0, [tblStock].[RemoveFromClearance] = 0) ) <> False)
GROUP BY 
    IIF ([tblStockMovementsDate] ! [LocationType] = 3, [tblShops] ! [Type], [tblLocationType] ! [LocationTypeDesc]),
    tblStockMovementsDate.[Location], 
    qryAllLocations.[WarehouseName],
    IIF ([tblShops] ! [Type] = 'Concession', 4, [tblStockMovementsDate] ! [LocationType])
ORDER BY
    IIF ([tblShops] ! [Type] = 'Concession', 4, [tblStockMovementsDate] ! [LocationType])
```

but it won't produce an output, instead I keep getting this error:

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
>   Error in list of function arguments: 'IS' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of syntax differences between Access and sql server. One major difference is how you reference objects. In Access it is [Table]![Column]. In sql server it is [Table].[Column]. No matter which DBMS you are using I would urge you not to code your entire queries on a single line. It is a nightmare to maintain. If you are on 2012 or later you can utilize an IIF similar to access. otherwise you will have to convert these to case expressions.

Comment: Have you converted all these other access queries to views? If so you may want to rethink how you are doing this. Nesting views in sql server is a recipe for some of the worst performance you can imagine. It seems totally logical but it just totally confuses the query engine.

Comment: yes i have converted all the queries to SQL as i am upgrading a old VB/access application to vb.net/sql server

Comment: So for example if "qryAllLocations" is now a view you do NOT want to create another view that selects from that view. That is a nested view and prevents sql from creating a good execution plan. It will return results but the performance is going to be sporadically awful. For more information see this article. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/

Comment: what would you suggest as this one and a few others that are used to create reports

Comment: You need to convert this query and ALL its underlying queries. You do not provide their syntax nor database schema (tables/fields/types). Come to think of it, this might be beyond StackOverflow Q&A purview as this is not a code writing service. Simply learn TSQL and apply it line by line. Much of SQL dialects are translatable across RDMSs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark. I did my best to decipher the code you posted originally.

I would recommend getting rid of those nested views. They are going to cause you serious anguish at some point. You will likely have to grab the queries from those views and move that to this query.

Notice how much cleaner this is when you use aliases instead of the Access default of slapping the table in front of every column. I also removed dozens of parenthesis groups that did nothing but make this hard to see. I also converted all your IIF expressions to case expressions since I don't know what version of sql you are using.

```
SELECT 
    case when smd.LocationType = 3 
        then tblShops.Type 
        else lt.LocationTypeDesc 
    end AS LocTypeDesc
    , smd.Location
    , al.WarehouseName
    , Sum((smd.MovementQtyHangers + (smd.MovementQtyBoxes * Isnull(g.GarmentsPerBox, 1))) * qryUnitPrice.UnitPrice) AS TotalValue
    , case when sh.Type = 'Concession' 
        then 4 
        else smd.LocationType 
    end AS LocType
FROM tblStockMovementsDate smd
INNER JOIN tblLocationType lt ON smd.LocationType = ll.LocationType
INNER JOIN qryAllLocations al ON smd.Location = al.WarehouseRef
LEFT JOIN qryGarmentsPerBox g ON smd.Location = g.WarehouseRef 
                                AND smd.StockCode = g.StockCode
LEFT JOIN qryUnitPrice up ON smd.StockCode = up.StockCode
LEFT JOIN tblShops sh ON smd.Location = sh.ShopRef
INNER JOIN tblStock st ON smd.StockCode = st.StockCode
WHERE tblShops.Clearance <> 0
    OR tblStock.DeadCode <> 0
    OR tblStock.RemoveFromClearance <> 0 
GROUP  BY case when smd.LocationType = 3 then tblShops.Type else lt.LocationTypeDesc end
    , smd.Location
    , al.WarehouseName
    , case when sh.Type = 'Concession' then 4 else smd.LocationType end
order by LocType
```

Comment: This database is going to be used on SQL server 2014 express

Comment: This is valid syntax for sql server.